# CI uri_string() Validation required?

Tags: validation, codeigniter, uri

I use codeigniter as my framework and in the top of my controllers I am going to add a line of code that will send the uri_string (the last page the user requested) to a library which will send it into the users session and possibly eventually into a database.

My question is whether or not I need to validate this uri_string() at all or whether it is safe as is?

Comment: Yes you should validate everything. Codeigniter will prohibit dodgey characters in the URL anyway and if you ensure that you're using ActiveRecord it escapes things appropriately anyway. I [posted an answer today which may be useful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937472/creating-back-page-links-in-codeignitor/8941073#8941073) about putting previously visited pages into the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `'permitted_uri_chars'` item in `config.php` will automatically prohibit any URL that contains non-permitted characters. So, as long as you haven't modified that to include potentially malicious characters, you should be ok. From the comments in `config.php`:

> By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-

However, [as Rooneyl mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8938833/30433), it probably wouldn't hurt anything to sanitize it anyway.

Comment: I haven't edited the default permitted uri chars so I think I'm not going to edit...I have a MY_Controller that Im putting this in the top of and I think there is no reason to run another instance of the validation class on every page load if there is no need to right

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, if in doubt validate it. 
For the short time it will take you to code it you will have peace of mind.

Also, if this is going to happen for all you controllers may I suggest that you either add the  function call to the construct of each controller or extend the core controller to include the call in its construct.