# creating back page links in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, browser-history

I have a page with URL [http://arslan/admin/category/index/0/name/asc/10](http://arslan/admin/category/index/0/name/asc/10%29) in Codeigniter.
In this URL, the `uri_segment` start from `0`. This (`0`) is the default search value, `name` and `asc` are the default sort field and order, and 10 is the pagination index.

Now if I move to an add page with URL (http://arslan/admin/category/add/)
similarly like above "add" is the current function.

Now if i want to go back through a link to back page... How can I divert the user back? I can't make the URL go back.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand the question correctly, if not please ignore my answer, but I think you want a link to "go back to previous page", similar to the back-button in a web browser.

If so you could use javascript to solve this by simply using this line:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);">Go back</a>
```

Comment: What is the previous visited link was from the other site :P

Answer (score 10):

I extend the session class by creating `/application/libaries/MY_Session.php`

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->tracker();
    }

    function tracker() {
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');

        $tracker =& $this->userdata('_tracker');

        if( !IS_AJAX ) {
            $tracker[] = array(
                'uri'   =>      $this->CI->uri->uri_string(),
                'ruri'  =>      $this->CI->uri->ruri_string(),
                'timestamp' =>  time()
            );
        }

        $this->set_userdata( '_tracker', $tracker );
    }


    function last_page( $offset = 0, $key = 'uri' ) {   
        if( !( $history = $this->userdata('_tracker') ) ) {
            return $this->config->item('base_url');
        }

        $history = array_reverse($history); 

        if( isset( $history[$offset][$key] ) ) {
            return $history[$offset][$key];
        } else {
            return $this->config->item('base_url');
        }
    }
}
```

And then to retrieve the URL of the last page visited you call

```
$this->session->last_page();
```

And you can increase the offset and type of information returned etc too

```
$this->session->last_page(1); // page before last
$this->session->last_page(2); // 3 pages ago
```

The function doesn't add pages called using Ajax to the tracker but you can easily remove the `if( !IS_AJAX )` bit to make it do so.

Edit:
If you run to the error Undefined constant IS_AJAX, assumed IS_AJAX
add the line below to `/application/config/constants.php`

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

Comment: Ben your suggestion is also helpful like @Ruben ..thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem. Any luck solving your problem?

Comment: I am already using session data - and when I run your code, I get the error: ```A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Filename: Session/Session.php

Backtrace:

File: /Nav_session.php
Line: 5
Function: __construct```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to solve your problem: First you could place a link that is using the javascript back-function onclick, like this ...

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">go back</a>
```

... or you always save the current full page url into a cookie and use that for generating the back link - a helper could look like this (not tested) ...

```
/**
 * save url to cookie
 */
if(!function_exists('urlhistory_save'))
{
    function urlhistory_save()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('session');

        $array = array(
            'oldUrl' = $CI->session->userdata('newurl'),
            'newurl' = $CI->uri->uri_string()
        );
        $CI->session->set_userdata($array);
    }
}

/**
 * get old url from cookie
 */
if(!function_exists('urlhistory_get'))
{
    function urlhistory_get()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('session');

        return $CI->session->userdata('oldurl');
    }
}
```

In your controller you would use urlhistory_save() to save the current URL and in the view youd could use urlhistory_get() to retreive the old address like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().urlhistory_get(); ?>go back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest way to redirect to your previous page ,  try this it work for me

```
 redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

you need to import user_agent library too `$this->load->library('user_agent');`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Session to go to back page as:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('ses_back_jobs','controller 
name'.array_pop(explode('controller name',$this->input->server('REQUEST_URI'),2))); //Back page
```

Then if u want to redirect to some page use it:

```
redirect($this->session->userdata('ses_back_jobs'));
```

or use it to the anchor.

Comment: get an error with this - Only variables should be passed by reference