# redirect back two steps codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

In codeingiter I have certain forms that when you submit it will then redirect back to the previous page using this.

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

I'm just wondering if there is a way to redirect back two steps for forms that have an actual page where they are editing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a server var that holds more than just the last URL. You'd need to store the URL's (either in a cookie, in the query-string, or in a server var) and then just redirect back as far as you'd want.

CodeIgniter Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941073/922522

You could also use Javascript:

```
window.location.history.go(-2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm! Much better than just redirecting my user back to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way using the referer variable to do this.
What you can do, however, is to store the path of the user in a session variable and do the redirection from this.

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller you can using this:**

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='javascript:history.back(-2);'</script>";
```

**or**

```
redirect("javascript:history.back(-2);");
```

**And with Alert message you can using this:**

```
echo "<script>alert('*Alert messages here...*');window.location.href='javascript:history.back(-2);'</script>";
```