# How to go back previous ajax url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, html, codeigniter-3

When page loaded http://something.com/user/mycourses address in the browser url. In the page there are two ajax requests are there. One is http://something.com/user/learnnow address(Shows learning courses) and http://something.com/user/teaching(shows teaching courses). If I click on teaching, ajax will load the page. If I click on browser back button to go to learnnow page, it takes me another url before mycourses page. I want when user click on browser back button it should go to learnow page from teaching page. How to do this please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating back page links in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937472/creating-back-page-links-in-codeigniter)

Comment: how to assign that to browser back button?

Comment: Go look into the HTML5 History API.