# How to enable the link based on the fetched id in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have two details page, each has a link "back to the listing page". There are two listing pages. Now I want when the user clicks on the link, it will take him out and will put him on previous page from where he came.
I've Interior page and Architect page, each of the page contains lots of profile and a link "view more" to end of each profile. Problem is when click on view more it redirecting to the ful details page but there is a link "back to the listing page" when click on that link i want to redirect the page to the previous page ( example: Came from interior page so click on back link option should take me to interior page )

I've done almost but need little help

```
<p class="link_back">
    <!-- <small> <a href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>">Back To List Page </a> </small> -->
      <?php
      $category = $article->category_id; // assuming this returns 1 or 0
       if($category == 1) {
         echo "(<small> <a href=' echo base_url('');'>Back To List Page </a> </small>)";
       } if($category == 3) {
       echo "(<small> <a href=' echo base_url('welcome/architect');'>Back To List Page </a> </small>)";
       } else {
       echo "(<small> <a href=' echo base_url('');'>Back To List Page </a> </small>)";
          }
           ?>
</p>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);">Go back</a>
The above answer works for me and I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937472/creating-back-page-links-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Window.history will be the answer for this in my option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();">Go back</a>
```